# Why is $D_5$ a subgroup of the icosahedral group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetry, platonic-solids

According to Wikipedia $D_5$ is a subgroup of the group of rotational symmetries of an icosahedron: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry. I know this isn't very rigorous, but intuitively this isn't obvious since I couldn't think of any way to map a pentagon ABCDE on an icosahedron (or dodecahedron) to the same pentagon, except with the vertices labeled AEDCB... at least not with just rotations in the icosahedral group (order 60). What would be the rigorous and geometric proofs for these facts?

Comment: $D_5$ is generated by two symmetries $r$ and $f$, with $r^5=1$, $f^2 = 1$, and $rf = fr^{-1}$.  X be an axis of the icosahedron through a pair of opposite vertices.  Let $r$ be a rotation of $108^\circ$ around this axis, and let $f$ be the $180^\circ$ rotation that exchanges the two endpoints of this axis. (It also exchanges every other pair of opposite vertices.)  Then it's easy to verify the three required relations $r^5=1$, $f^2 = 1$, and $rf = fr^{-1}$.

Comment: Now I feel dumb, haha. One remaining question: you said "let $f$ be **the** $180^\circ$ rotation that... Aren't there ten such rotations, i.e., this isn't unique? Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two vertices both adjacent to the same pole being used for $r$... then rotating about the edge $v_1v_2$ gives an $f$ right? Essentially, rotating along any edge that wasn't in "the middle", or touching the top or bottom vertex would give $f$, right? There are ten of these...

Comment: You're right, it's not unique.  There is one such rotation for each pair of opposite pentagons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put one vertex ($Z$) of the icosahedron on top, and one ($Z'$) on the bottom, touching the table.

The top vertex $Z$ is adjacent to five vertices $A,B,C,D,E$ that form a regular pentagon.  $Z'$ is adjacent to the five remaining vertices $A', B', C', D', E'$, which also form a regular pentagon.  For each $x$ in $\{A,B,C,D,E,Z\}$, the vertex $x$ is opposite to $x'$.

Let $r$ be a rotation of the icosahedron by $108^\circ$ around the axis $ZZ'$. This rotation permutes the vertices as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
Z&Z'&A&A'&B&B'&C&C'&D&D'&E&E' \\
Z&Z'&B&B'&C&C'&D&D'&E&E'&A&A'
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Let $f$ be a rotation of the icosahedron that exchanges $Z$ and $Z'$.  This turns the entire solid upside down, exchanging the positions of pentagons $ABCDE$ and $A'B'C'D'E'$.  It permutes the vertices as follows:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
Z&Z'&A&A'&B&B'&C&C'&D&D'&E&E' \\
Z'&Z&A'&A&B'&B&C'&C&D'&D&E'&E
\end{pmatrix}.$$

By direct calculation, one can find that $$\begin{align}
r^5 & = 1 \\
f^2 & = 1 \\
rf & = fr^{-1}
\end{align}
$$